# Mix one time binding and two-way binding with ngClass

Tags: angularjs, binding, ng-class

Is it possible to mix one time bindings and two-way bindings in the same expression?

What I've tried so far:

```
//Both will be one time binding
ng-class="::{test: testCond, test2: test2Cond}"

//Doens't work
ng-class="{::test: testCond, test2: test2Cond}"

//Can't have two of them
ng-class="::{test: testCond}" ng-class="{test2: test2Cond}"

//Doesn't work
ng-class="{{::testCond?'test':''}} {{::testCond2?'test2':''}}"
```

So, is this possible?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out or find a workaround? I'm curious myself.

Comment: @NoahB No, i used a workaround! 
//One time binding in ng-class directive | two-way binding in regular class attr
ng-class="::{test: testCond}" class="{{}}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-class one time binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767044/ng-class-one-time-binding)

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> I used a workaround:

```
 //One time binding in ng-class directive | two-way binding in regular class       

 attr ng-class="::{test: testCond}" class="{{}}"
```